# AWS EBS Nextjs App not working with custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've published my app with elasticbeanstalk. And it works well with default elasticbeanstalk domain (http://blabla.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com)

Then I try to assign a domain by Route 53. (classic routing with alias)
And then, I added ssl certificate from EBS configuration. (Added listener, and certificate)

After I did this, I tried to connect test.blabla.com and It doesnt connect.

My server.js file:

```
const cli = require('next/dist/cli/next-start');

cli.nextStart([
  '-p', process.env.PORT || 3000,
  '-H', process.env.HOSTNAME || '0.0.0.0',
]);
```

What should I make to let It work well with custom domain&https.

Comment: Did you solve this problem sir? I'm facing same issue. Could you share your solution if you resolve this?